# Remote page content in Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova

I have a phonegap ios app that has several features running locally however for one page I'd like to display remote content within a section of the page. This would be used for something like the latest news about the app that could then be updated remotely and the app pull in the data. Ideally bringing in a page.

I have tried iframe but even with all urls allowed the iframe is blank. Is there another solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 2.3 Phonegap includes [InAppBrowser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser), you can use it to open the external urls, or you can use childbrowser plugin

Comment: Hiya is there a way to use in InAppBrowser in a sort of frame so it doesn't use the whole page?

Comment: I don't thnk so. If you want to get info from the server to show it inside your app you should use XHR calls